# Can't send up generic base64 image to API using filepath

Tags: c#, .net, cloudinary

So I'm trying to send up a base64 string of an image to Cloudinary. Everything works except for one bit, the filepath. There is no real file path as the file is not saved.

This is how it should look (with the @ at the start):

```
var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
{
    File = new FileDescription(@"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==")
};
```

This is how I'm doing it:

```
var param = ("data:image/png;base64," + file);
// file is equal to the string (param gives the correct value that I'm looking for)

var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
{
    File = new FileDescription(param)
};
```

I've tried these:

```
// 1

var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
{
    File = new FileDescription(@param)
};

// 2

var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
{
    File = new FileDescription(@ + param)
};

// 3

var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
{
    File = new FileDescription((@param).ToString())
};
```

But these don't work and I really have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Check here. There you can see valid usages from many open source projects: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/CloudinaryDotNet.Actions/ImageUploadParams/-/php-imageuploadparams-class-examples.html

Comment: What's wrong with your second code-snippet? The `@` in your first snippet is a [verbatim identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) and does not really have anything to do with the contents of your string, it just allows you to avoid stuff like explicitly escaping special characters in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link by @Oguz Ozgul you solution would be:

```
string dataImageBase64 = @"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
string pattern = "data:.*?base64,";
string base64string = Regex.Replace(dataImageBase64, pattern, "");
Stream imageStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64string));
var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams
{
    File = new FileDescription("Picture", imageStream)
};
```